# Why does a combined call to random.randint and random.sample in a loop lead to a repeating output sequence?

Tags: python, random

I am confused by the behaviour of the following code using `random` in python:

```py
SEED = ... # see below for some examples

for _ in range(100):
    k = random.randint(1, 21)
    print(k)

    random.seed(SEED)
    s = random.sample(population=range(100), k=k)
```

I would expect the first `print(k)` to output a random number between 1 and 21, and the next 99 `print(k)` statements to always output the same random number, because the random seed is set to the same value in each iteration of the for loop.

Instead, I see several random values of `k` in the first few iterations, before the `k` sequence seemingly enters a repeating sequence once one of the repeating values is hit. The length of the sequence varies depending on the value of `SEED`.

A few examples to illustrate this (first occurrence of the repeating sequence in **bold**):

- `SEED = 4841` --> k = 14 **1 21** 1 21 1 21 ...
- `SEED = 5733` --> k = 9 16 10 **6 4 11** 6 4 11 6 4 11 ...
- `SEED = 22`     --> k = 19 14 **2 1 8 21 14** 2 1 8 21 14 2 1 8 21 14 ...
- `SEED = 31`     --> k = 19 17 **5** 5 5 ...

Some observations I've made trying to understand this:

- Printing the sample `s` shows the same behaviour, i.e. given the same `SEED`, the same value `k` always yields the same value of `s` (as I would expect).
- When I move the line `random.seed(SEED)` to the top of the for loop, I always get the same value of k as expected.
- This really seems to be rooted in the interaction between `random.randint` and `random.sample` and the fact that I pass `k` as an argument. When I comment out the last line of the for loop or replace it with another call to `random.randint` or pass some fixed value like `k=5`, I get the expected behaviour of a constant sequence of `k`.

But I still don't understand why this leads to these repeating sequences, can anyone explain?

Comment: You forget that you're calling `random.sample` after calling `random.seed` and before calling `random.randint`.  If the calls to `random.sample` were exactly the same, then you would indeed see the repetition you expect.  But they're not the same.  The value of `k`, which determines how many values are generated, differs.  Therefore, the subsequent values of `k` differ as well.  Try passing a constant `k` to `random.sample` and then see if it does what you expect.

Comment: @TomKarzes This much I understand, see my last two bullet points. Sorry if that wasn't expressed clearly. I do indeed get the expected behaviour when passing a fixed value of `k` as you suggest. To clarify, I guess my real question is why this leads to these _repeating sequences_.

Comment: @Clang `random.sample(range(n), k=k)` is a bit like `[random.randrange(n) for _ in range(k)]` but with the additional constraint that draws are done "without replacement".  i.e. it's going to be advancing the random state at least "`k` times".  in practice the random state produces 32bit unsigned integers and you might need more than one to produce one draw from `random.randrange`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Tom pointed out in the comments you're generating `k` random numbers, which takes at least `k` calls (Python uses [rejection sampling](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3b8bcfc78985b952cf7e17c97713963cc9b875e8/Lib/random.py#L235) to ensure draws aren't biased) to the underlying RNG.

You could fix your example by doing something like:

```
import random

SEED = ... # see below for some examples
MAX_K = 21

for _ in range(100):
    k = random.randint(1, MAX_K)
    print(k)

    random.seed(SEED)
    s = random.sample(population=range(100), k=MAX_K)[:k]
```

but this obviously comes at a cost of drawing more values than you're likely to use.

Some RNGs [support "seeking"](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/bit_generators/generated/numpy.random.PCG64.advance.html) but seeks tend to be relatively expensive (compared to drawing a random number) so this might not help this example, as you're only expecting to draw a few extra values. Further, the difficultly in determining how many rejections you're about to get would mean you'd probably need at least one run with `k = MAX_K` to discover how far ahead you need to seek.

Update: to explain why you get these repeating sequences lets rearrange your code:

```
SEED = ...

graph = {}
for k in range(1, 22):
    random.seed(SEED)
    random.sample(population=range(100), k=k)
    graph[k] = random.randint(1, 21)
```

This uses the random number generator the same as your original code, but generates a [graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(discrete_mathematics)) showing that if the previous iteration evaluated to a given `k` then what would the next round give.

If I run this for `SEED = 22` I get the following graph:

[image: graphviz output]

showing the cycle that you saw in your question.  The image was created by [graphviz](https://graphviz.org/) if you want to do something similar.

Comment: Thanks, this and your comment helped me understand why this is not behaving as I initially expected. I can fix my initial use case, but what I still don't get theoretically is why this leads to these repeating sequences. In other words, why isn't k completely random, but instead the RNG after a while keeps producing e.g. consecutive 5s for k (in the case of SEED=31).

Comment: @Clang hopefully that makes it clearer!